# Why Ionic 2 builds are so large, even for small / blank apps?

Tags: javascript, cordova, browser, build, ionic2

So I'm new to Ionic, and might be missing something. But I started a new blank app like so:

`ionic start BlankApp --v2 blank`

then added a browser platform:

`cordova platform add browser`

and then built for production:

`ionic build browser`

The output looks like this:

```
> ionic-hello-world@ ionic:build C:\Work\ionic\BlankApp
> ionic-app-scripts build

keywords if/then/else require v5 option
[17:56:25]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.47
[17:56:25]  build dev started ...
[17:56:25]  clean started ...
[17:56:25]  clean finished in 3 ms
[17:56:25]  copy started ...
[17:56:25]  transpile started ...
[17:56:28]  transpile finished in 3.47 s
[17:56:28]  webpack started ...
[17:56:28]  copy finished in 3.65 s
[17:56:34]  webpack finished in 5.65 s
[17:56:34]  sass started ...
[17:56:35]  sass finished in 1.45 s
[17:56:35]  build dev finished in 10.73 s

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.

Error loading cordova-browser


Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Work\ionic\BlankApp\platforms\browser\cordova\build.bat""


Cleaning Browser project
```

I was expecting a small js bundle given that this app has nothing in it. Tree-shaking was supposed to have dropped a lot of code and the app was supposed, I think, but be lightening fast.

Unfortunately, that's not what happened.

The `platforms/browser/www/build/js` directory has a `main.js` file that is over 4MBs in size. There is also a main.css file with 500Kb of content.

What am I missing? am I looking in the wrong spot?

**UPDATE: ** My issue is that I'm trying to build a progressive web app. If I only wanted to build a mobile app, that'd be fine. But for a web app to download 4MB of stuff before even counting it's own content is crazy, I can't believe that is the state of the union on an RC4 release.

Thank you,

Eduardo

Comment: If you're making a web app, you should probably just code it in pure HTMJ+JS+CSS, instead of using ionic. It'll save you a lot of space, and probably a lot of trouble. I don't think Ionic or Cordova were meant for that at all.

Comment: I was hoping to have one codebase and be able to wrap that web app as native apps as well. Ionic has support for Progressive Web Apps as one of its flagship features, therefore my question. Something must be off...

Answer (score 7):

use **ionic build browser --prod**

Comment: I'm not sure about Ionic 2 since I've only worked with Ionic 1, but I can remember that the default build action includes alot of code used for debuging. Using the --prod flag greatly reduced the file size for my Ionic 1 app, back in the days ;-)

Comment: Ionic devs recommend `npm run build --prod` but it may be the same result.

Comment: @DmitriR117 and that result, in 2017 September, is still over 500kb. vendor.js is 800+ kb

Comment: I am testing ionic 4.1.1 with a basic `ionic start myapp tabs --type=ionic-angular` demo. `ionic build --prod`, `ionic build browser --prod` and `npm run build --prod` all result in 3.4mb of the `www` folder

Answer (score 1):

When you think a bit about it, it's quite logic that your build is large. It's because, inside the build, there is Cordova and all its dependencies and plugins. But when you see that `main.js` and `main.css` are quite large, it's because of Cordova who's trying to put every library, plugins, etc... in the same file.

But, could you upload those 2 files, just to see if I'm right. :)

Comment: The thing is, for a development build that'd be fine. I cannot imagine how in the world this is OK for a production build of an app that has nothing in it. Wasn't tree shaking supposed to be dropping all of cordova and all of the plugins, given that I'm not using them? There are even source maps generated, and lots of comments. The main.js is not even minified. I don't understand what's going on, but this is not a prod build which is strange given that Ionic 2 is in RC4....